# ¿"Mover" y "apartar" son sinónimos?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

1. ¿Hay "mover la mirada"?
2. ¿Son lo mismo significado "`apartar la mirada`" y "`mover la mirada`"?
3. ¿Hay alguna diferencia en significado entre ellas?

Busqué el diccionario y los sinónimos de `apartar` son como 
`retirar, alejar, separar, rechazar....`.

No hay "`mover`"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ***apartar*** la mirada de [algo]/[alguien] viene siendo algo así como: *dejar de mirar.*
- ***mover*** la mirada netamente se refiere a cambiar la dirección que estás viendo, pero no implica necesariamente que dejes de verlo.

Comment: Sí, creo.. [mover](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PxKjVlC) y [apartar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=35yJCXM) en el DLE (del RAE).

Comment: @Ustanak : `dejar de verlo` = not to see it?

Comment: @Cadenza *stop watching it.*

Comment: @Ustanak: means your are no longer looking at it?

Comment: @Cadenza Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Diría que **no** son sinónimos. Si bien en la frase "`apártate del fuego`" o "`apartar la mirada`" se infiere que existe movimiento y podría pensarse que `apartarse` y `moverse` son sinónimos, son dos palabras que expresan acciones diferentes, lo cual se evidencia en la frase "`se apartaron los caminos`" o "`se apartaron las ideas`", donde no se evidencia movimiento alguno.

Por lo tanto la palabra `apartar`

> Separar, desunir, dividir.
>
> Quitar a alguien o algo del lugar donde estaba, para dejarlo desocupado

no es sinónimo de `mover`

> Trasladar, desplazar, mudar.
>
> Hacer que un cuerpo deje el lugar o espacio que ocupa y pase a ocupar
> otro.

Answer (score 1):

**Mover** es una palabra general que se refiere a cambiar la posición de un objeto. Hay muchas formas de mover algo y también muchas condiciones en las que este movimiento se realiza.

**Apartar** es una forma específica de mover un objeto, siempre *desde* un punto de referencia *hacia* otro punto que está en una posición *separada*.

Entonces hay otras formas de mover objetos sin que necesariamente se estén apartando: acercar, centrar, correr, girar...

Como ocurre siempre en cualquier idioma, en una frase específica (como la que tú propones) dos palabras que no son sinónimos léxicos pueden funcionar como sinónimos contextuales. En *mover la mirada* y *apartar la mirada*, "mover" y "apartar" son tan sinónimos entre sí como "sal" y "salero" en *pásame la sal* y *pásame el salero*.